# How does "hard" come to mean "close"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-usage

His pursuers were **hard** on his heels, so he hid in a thicket **hard** by. The first use of "hard" means close in time and the second use means close in distance. Was there an early use of "hard" just to mean close? Does a hard-edge abstraction refer to a painting in which changes occur close by? (This last question, seems to be a stretch, but I've never heard anyone talk about a hard-edge knife.) I know "hard on his heels" sounds like close in distance, but that's not how it's used: cf. Cambridge Dictionary Online come/follow hard/hot on the heels of sth
​
"to happen very soon after something"

Comment: There's also "hard left" for a quick left turn.

Comment: @rajah9: Hard left refers to the amount of turning, not to how quickly you turn. It distinguishes, for example, between two paths that turn to the left, one at a greater angle of turn than the other.

Comment: @Drew, good point. I can imagine a hard left for an angle greater than, say, 90 degrees, which would entail more turning. I can also imagine a chase scene in a movie where "hard left" means to turn into an alley. The angle is still 90 degrees, but the driving must be precise. And consider the sailing command: "hard to port"? I see this meaning both turning quickly and at a greater angle.

Comment: @rajah9: Not to mention the sailing term "*hard a-lee*".

Comment: As rajah9 and Drew suggest, "hard" is a nautical term.  Turning "hard a-lee" means pushing the tiller hard to the lee side of the boat (which turns the boat windward), and "hard to port" means to push the tiller strongly to the port (left) side, turning the boat right.  The expression "hard by" is also used in sailing to imply coming alongside another boat or a dock or some such, and the expression likely is related to the effort involved in this maneuver.

Comment: I actually think the 'hard-edge' association makes it all the easier to use the word even though it by far isn't the primary meaning. Hard against each other sort of conjures up being slapped edge to edge.  Hard means un-moving/set as well as 'very'.  Also, the usage becomes a self-fuffilling connection.. "hard right" means take a right a close as possible.. so it beings to mean "close" even though it initially referred to the difficulty or magnitude of force to turn right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not the word "hard" but the word "by" that means "close to", as evidenced by this excerpt from [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=by&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **by (prep.)** - Old English be- (unstressed) or bi (stressed) "**near**, in,
>   by, during, about," from Proto-Germanic *bi "around, about" (source
>   also of Old Saxon and Old Frisian bi "by near," Middle Dutch bie,
>   Dutch bij, German bei "by, at, near," Gothic bi "about"), from *umbi
>   (cognate with second element in PIE *ambhi "around;" see ambi-).

In light of this, "hard" is likely meant as an intensifier, indicating that the thicket in your example sentence is *very* close to the man being pursued.  This sense of the word "hard" is in turn evidenced by *this* excerpt from [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=hard&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **hard (adj.)** - Old English heard "solid
>   and firm, not soft," also, "difficult to endure, carried on with great
>   exertion," also, of persons, "severe, rigorous, harsh, cruel," from
>   Proto-Germanic *hardu- (source also of Old Saxon hard, Old Frisian
>   herd, Dutch hard, Old Norse harðr "hard," Old High German harto
>   "**extremely, very**," German hart, Gothic hardus "hard"), from PIE
>   *kortu- (source also of Greek kratos "strength," kratys "strong"), suffixed form of root *kar-/*ker- "hard."

Comment: Excellent answer. That point had escaped me when I wrote my earlier comment. Less obviously the case with *hard on (his heels)*, since the preposition *on* is not being used literally. But both *hard by* and *hard on (his heels)* are idiomatic in modern English.

Comment: I am a little surprised that in its voluminous entry on *hard* in all its possible senses, the OED does not contain the idiomatic forms we are considering here. Perhaps the answer can be found in the very first, sense 1, definition of *hard* which is *Not soft; resistant to force or pressure; firm, solid, unyielding; robust.*. I think *unyielding* is important here, especially with *hard on his heels*.